# How should you install QtOpenGL to make cmake be able to find it?

Tags: package-management, qt, opengl, cmake

I have [this exact problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20677967/cmake-cant-find-qt-opengl-library) while attempting to install Extcalc from scource:

```
ezio@Cantabury ~/Downloads/extcalc-0.9.3-1 $ cmake .
-- Looking for Q_WS_X11
-- Looking for Q_WS_X11 - found
-- Looking for Q_WS_WIN
-- Looking for Q_WS_WIN - not found.
-- Looking for Q_WS_QWS
-- Looking for Q_WS_QWS - not found.
-- Looking for Q_WS_MAC
-- Looking for Q_WS_MAC - not found.
-- Found Qt-Version 4.8.7 (using /usr/bin/qmake)
Qt QTOPENGL library not found.
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/ezio/Downloads/extcalc-0.9.3-1
```

The solution there was to "go back building Qt and take extra care that you enable build of the QtOpenGL module." The thing is I installed everything, including Qt, via apt-get, and I think I also have QtOpenGl installed. Specifically, during the attempt to get it work, I installed these packages (in addition to some other core Qt modules I already had on the system):

```
libqt4-opengl, python-qt4-gl, build-essential, qt4-dev-tools, libqt4-dev
```

and also the package list suggested by Mazze there:

```
apt-get install libfontconfig1-dev libfreetype6-dev libx11-dev libxext-dev libxfixes-dev libxi-dev libxrender-dev libxcb1-dev libx11-xcb-dev libxcb-glx0-dev libxcb-keysyms1-dev libxcb-image0-dev libxcb-shm0-dev libxcb-icccm4-dev libxcb-sync0-dev libxcb-xfixes0-dev libxcb-shape0-dev libxcb-randr0-dev libxcb-render-util0-dev
```

I couldn't find any other rescources online about installing QtOpenGl (without the whole Qt package).

- **How could I check if I indeed have this module installed?**
- **If I have, how could I make cmake find it?**
- **If not, what would be the simplest way to install it?**

Here is the part of my CMakeList.txt I think may be relevant. Cutouts indicated by [...].

```
PROJECT(extcalc)


CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.4.3 FATAL_ERROR)

if(POLICY CMP0005)
  cmake_policy(SET CMP0005 OLD)
endif(POLICY CMP0005)


FIND_PACKAGE(Qt4 REQUIRED)

ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DQT3_SUPPORT)

SET( CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release )

SET( QT_USE_QT3SUPPORT TRUE )
SET( QT_USE_QTOPENGL TRUE )
SET( QT_USE_QTGUI TRUE )

INCLUDE(${QT_USE_FILE})

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${QT_INCLUDE_DIR}
                    ${QT_INCLUDE_PATH}
                    src/
                    .)

SET(CPACK_INSTALL_CMAKE_PROJECTS "/home/user/Projekte/extcalc;Extcalc;ALL;/")
SET(CPACK_PACKAGE_DESCRIPTION_SUMMARY "Scientific Graphic Calculator")
SET(CPACK_PACKAGE_VENDOR "")
SET(CPACK_PACKAGE_DESCRIPTION_FILE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/README")
SET(CPACK_RESOURCE_FILE_LICENSE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/COPYING")
SET(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION "0.9.3")
SET(CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME "extcalc")

SET(CPACK_PACKAGE_INSTALL_DIRECTORY "CMake ${CMake_VERSION_MAJOR}.${CMake_VERSION_MINOR}")
SET(CPACK_STRIP_FILES "bin/extcalc")
SET(CPACK_SOURCE_STRIP_FILES "")
SET(CPACK_PACKAGE_EXECUTABLES "extcalc;extcalc")
SET(CPACK_GENERATOR "TGZ")
SET(CPACK_SOURCE_GENERATOR "TGZ")
SET(CPACK_SOURCE_IGNORE_FILES "CVS/")
#Debian speciefic
SET(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_ARCHITECTURE "i386")
SET(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_DEPENDS "libc6 , libgcc1, libgl1-mesa-glx | libgl1, libglu1-mesa | libglu1, libqtcore4, libqt4-qt3support , libstdc++6, libx11-6, libxext6, libxft2")
SET(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_MAINTAINER "Rainer Strobel <rainer1223@users.sourceforge.net>")
SET(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_DESCRIPTION "Extcalc is a multifunctional scientific graphic calculator for Linux with features like graph drawing, graph analysis and calculation of scientific functions. Extcalc also provides an integrated programming language.")
SET(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_SECTION "math")
SET(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_PRIORITY "optional")

SET(CPACK_RPM_PACKAGE_ARCHITECTURE "i386")
SET(CPACK_RPM_PACKAGE_LICENSE "GPL")
SET(CPACK_RPM_PACKAGE_GROUP "Productivity/Schientific/Math")
SET(CPACK_RPM_PACKAGE_VENDOR "Rainer Strobel <rainer1223@users.sourceforge.net>")
SET(CPACK_RPM_PACKAGE_DESCRIPTION "Extcalc is a multifunctional scientific graphic calculator for Linux with features like graph drawing, graph analysis and calculation of scientific functions. Extcalc also provides an integrated programming language.")


INCLUDE(CPack)


SET([...]
)


QT4_ADD_RESOURCES(qrc_cxx ${src_qrc})

QT4_WRAP_CPP(moc_cxx ${moc_h})

QT4_WRAP_UI(ui_h ${src_ui})



SET(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX "/usr/local")
SET(SHAREDIR "share/extcalc/data")
SET(DOCDIR "share/extcalc/doc")
SET(DESKTOPDIR "share/applications")
SET(ICONDIR "share/icons")
SET(MANDIR "/usr/man")
SET(BINDIR "bin")
ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DINSTALLDIR=\"\\\"${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/share/extcalc\\\"\")


#installer data
INSTALL(FILES
[...]
)

ADD_EXECUTABLE(extcalc WIN32 ${src_cxx} ${src_h} ${moc_cxx} ${moc_ui_cxx} ${src_ui_cxx} ${ui_h} ${qrc_cxx})
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(extcalc ${QT_LIBRARIES})

  INSTALL(TARGETS extcalc RUNTIME DESTINATION bin
      PERMISSIONS OWNER_EXECUTE OWNER_WRITE OWNER_READ
          GROUP_EXECUTE GROUP_READ
          WORLD_EXECUTE WORLD_READ)
```

Comment: Support for compiling packages outside of the Ubuntu repositories is going to be limited. In the past when I tried compiling packages with qt dependencies I found it to be difficult, you may need versions of Qt packages that are not in the ubuntu repositories meaning you may need to compile more things rather then just install stuff from the ubuntu repos. Ask the maintainer of the Extcalc source code.

Comment: Also read the answers in the link you gave "./configure --help" and `./configure -multimedia -opengl` seems you have a bit of compiling to do. Note the configure is for compiling Qt so ....

Comment: Did you install just the **runtime** library package `libqt4-opengl` or the **development** package  `libqt4-opengl-dev`?

Comment: @steeldriver thanks, it made things better. Now it complains about something else: `CMakeFiles/extcalc.dir/src/graphout.o: undefined reference to symbol 'glNewList'` though I have opengl installed (specifically, I tried to install ~freeglut3, freeglut3-dev, libglew-dev libsdl2-dev libsdl2-image-dev libglm-dev libfreetype6-dev`. Should I ask a new question on this, or could you find what's missing?

Comment: @Neinstein maybe `libgl1-mesa-dev`?